# Get the google search query that brought a user to your site

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible to obtain that info with javascript from your site? Without any 3rd party plugins.

I know `document.referrer`, but that does not yield the whole query, just the domain. I would like to use the information to display the user more specific data without him "having to look again" when he already types what he is looking for into google.

Comment: I don't thik it's possible, maybe someone can point that I'm wrong with this, though.

Comment: I agree with @Teemu that it's not possible to do so.

Comment: @RifatBinReza Basically yes. So the answer is simply "no, doesn't work".

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. But I'm not sure why it doesn't work. There should be a way for it. Could be security reason as some websites keep different type of tokens in the query string.

Comment: @RifatBinReza Yeah definitely security (and also privacy). If this would suddenly be possible, I guess that this could propose an unwanted risk to other websites. Also, it is a bit "workaroundy". Google should already find the relevant content on a website in the first place, without the website itself needing to take over this responsibility. But sometimes there are use cases where this would still be a handy feature. :)